# Create the Store Procedure to Update the value in bulk format

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one table having 100,000 records approx. such as:-

```
Table A
Name     city
abc      NYC
bcd      DC
cde      TX
fre      CA
grt      NYC
............
```

I want to update this table from city name `'NYC'` to `'CA'` and from `'PL'` to `'NYC'` having huge record to update city name by using Store Procedure in bulk format then how we can use this.

Comment: Please do not change the question such that both answers are not valid anymore

Comment: 'Create a stored procedure to...' in the title is redundant given the `plsql` tag.

Comment: 100000 rows is not considered "huge" by any standard. There is no need to do this with a stored procedure. A simple, single UPDATE will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to create a procedure

```
create procedure updateNYCtoCA
as
begin
  update tableA
  set name = 'CA'
  where name = 'NYC';
  commit;
end;
```

**EDIT**

Code change due to question has been edited

```
create procedure updatewhatever
as
begin
  update tableA
  set name = (case name when 'NYC' then 'CA' else 'NYC') 
  where name = 'NYC' or name = 'PL';
  commit;
end;
```